# Is PHP Mongodb driver sort() method deprecated or not?

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting

I need to migrate PHP application from old Mongo driver to new and I am not sure if is correct to use `$collection->find()->sort()->limit()` call. [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/) does not mention sort() and limit() methods only options param in find(). Why? IDE shows me the sort method but I dont know if it is correct. Also [MongoCursor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php) class does not have any sort method.
Thanks.

Comment: `old to new` could you specify versions please?

Comment: Version of PHP is 7.2 I dont know the version of Mongo driver. I need to migrate from PHP 5.x

Comment: either you have `mongo` (old) or `mongodb` (new) driver.

Comment: I thing PHP 7 is compatible only with new one. Eg. MongoDate is replaced with UTCDateTime.